# Wordpress - Show admin bar only to the post author

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to show the admin bar on my single.php page ONLY when the actual author of the post is on the page.
I took this article as a reference and was able to make the admin bar visible on single.php pages only, but I also want to add a condition to hide it to non-author viewers.
https://second-cup-of-coffee.com/hiding-the-wordpress-admin-bar-on-certain-pages/

And this is the code I tried on my functions.php:

```
function my_theme_hide_admin_bar($bool) {

  $logged_in_user        =  wp_get_current_user();
  $logged_in_user_id     =  $logged_in_user->ID;

  if ( ! is_single() && $logged_in_user_id !== get_the_author_meta('ID') ) :
    return false;
  else :
    return $bool;
  endif;
}
add_filter('show_admin_bar', 'my_theme_hide_admin_bar');
```

However, the admin bar still shows when I view a post from another author.

Comment: You might want to post this over on https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've got to compare the two ID's, the one from the post author and the one from the current user. We also want to make sure that the user is an actual author for redundancy.

| Function | Description |
| --- | --- |
| `get_post_field( 'post_author' )` | [Retrieve data from a post field based on Post ID.](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_field/) |
| `get_current_user_id()` | [Get the current user’s ID.](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_current_user_id/) |
| `current_user_can( 'author' )` | [Returns whether the current user has the specified capability.](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/current_user_can/) |

```
<?php
add_filter( 'show_admin_bar', function( $show ) {
  if( is_single() && current_user_can( 'author' ) && get_post_field( 'post_author' ) == get_current_user_id() ) {
    return $show;
  } else {
    return;
  };
} ); ?>
```

---

### EDIT:

> While checking against particular roles in place of a capability is supported in part, this practice is discouraged as it may produce unreliable results.

- Source @ https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/current_user_can/#description

Having that in mind using `current_user_can( 'author' )` isn't considered best practice. Instead an actual capability handle should be used. You can refer to the [Roles and Capabilities page](https://wordpress.org/support/article/roles-and-capabilities/) for a complete list of users and capabilities.

I decided to use the `export` capability, but you can use anything from [Capability vs. Role Table](https://wordpress.org/support/article/roles-and-capabilities/#capability-vs-role-table).

```
<?php
  add_filter( 'show_admin_bar', function( $show ) {
    if( is_single() && current_user_can( 'export' ) && get_post_field( 'post_author' ) == get_current_user_id() ) {
      return $show;
    } else {
      return;
    };
} ); ?>
```

---

Special thanks to **@Xhynk** in the comments for the tips and the optimization.

Comment: `$post_id` isn't defined in the scope of the `show_admin_bar` filter. You'll need to use `get_the_ID()` or `global $post; $post->ID;`. Otherwise, +1 (also I dig the table function reference, I may start using that)

Comment: Also since the return value is dual-conditional, the `is_single()` check could be combined into a single return ternary: `return (is_single() && get_post_field('post_author', get_the_ID()) == get_current_user_id()) ? $show : false;` - returns false if not single or not the owner of the post, otherwise returns their personal setting value.

Comment: Whew, still working through my morning (early afternoon) coffee lol. It's because it's passing as `null`, which `get_post_field()` will assume the `global $post` from. So you can replace it with just `get_post_field( 'post_author' )`, no need for the second parameter!

Comment: Thank you so much both @amarinediary and @Xhynk ! I tried the code provided but did not work in the beginning, but I removed the second condition `current_user_can( 'author' )` and it worked! This is probably because I am using a custom role for the author using Ultimate Member plugin. Would be appreciated if you could point out any potential concerns based on this removal.
Thanks again!

Comment: Yes exactly,  I added it as a redundancy, usually you want to avoid changing Wordpress default permission.

Comment: You can specify your custom role instead of the 'author', it should work.

Comment: No risk associated, as the ID is already unique, it should be enough.